# Is there a better way to set lots of required properties than sending as parameters in a Constructor?

Tags: c#

I have a class that in order to do it's job needs to have 8 different property values set.
I want to make sure that all 8 properties are set before trying to execute a method. 
I currently have all the parameters passed in and set via the constructor.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I see quite a few APIs like this - if you ask me, they need to be fixed.

Comment: As a general rule, having more than three parameters for a method (or ctor) is confusing.

Comment: There are better answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064505/how-to-force-a-client-to-set-certain-properties

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can allow the object to be created  without specifying values for all the properties and then the method would throw an `InvalidOperationException` if called before the object state is valid for the method call to execute, which in this case would mean that all 8 properties  would have valid values.

This way you give more flexibility to the consumer. It can create a new instance at one moment, set it's properties at another and only then call the method. This is a "pattern" that is used through the .NET codebase and to which developers are already used.

---

**Update:**

This also simplifies things if you're adding other methods that don't need the full set of properties to be initialized. Yes we could add another constructor overload with the new set of properties, but what if we have 2 methods that both need one property of the same type to be initialized? This is not solvable by using constructor overloads.

Comment: Could you explain why this is better than using the constructor and having compile-time safety?

Comment: An extension of this idea is to use Code Contracts.

Comment: I use this in a specific circumstance. When collecting input for a gui.  I have an model which has properties for each thing that can be set from the gui and the gui object sets those properties when the gui is changed.  the object can then be verified to see that everything on the form is set correctly.  but generally I prefer using the constructor and having compile time safety.  Having said that even the constructor can't protect you from passing null when its not allowed...

Comment: give me a compile time error over a run time error anytime. this might be a commonly used pattern but i don't like it personally.

Comment: @Dan Diplo, I find it better because it adds more flexibility as stated in the original answer. However, I updated the answer with another scenario that you may find relevant.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet, the constructor would have to validate the properties, which in turn is something that most of the times needs to be done at runtime, so I believe this is not an issue of compile time error vs runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion if a class requires these 8 objects in order to function then they should be passed into the constructor and by no other means. I'm a big fan of dependency injection anyway, but this method also allows for better unit testing by passing in mocked objects and such.

Answer (score 2):

you could consolidate the parameters into a [Parameter Object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object) and just pass that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using this class from XAML you would make all 8 properties individually settable and throw an exception if somebody tries to execute a method without them all set. It's also possible that you would want to "freeze" the object once a method was called and throw an exception if somebody tries to set a property on a "frozen" object.

I'm not going to pass judgement on which method is better, though.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is the only way to do it at compile time.  The other option would be to throw an exception if not all the parameters have been set.

Answer (score 0):

Give them default values?
Maybe you can give a bit more of the context to let us help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object initializer if you are using c# 3.0 onwards. This is arbitrary whether it's 'better' or not.

Comment: looks prettier, seems worse for style

Answer (score 0):

Use setter in the properties. When property is used by the method and it is not set already, `setter` would do it for you. This is not the recommended approach thogh but might be needed in some situations.

Some thing similar would work

```
    Class SomeClass        
    {
     string name;
     string Name 
     { 
       set 
       {
        if (name  == null) 
         name  = value; 
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor sounds like the best way to do this since it will be verified at compile tile. Of course, you could have default values for some or all of the properties and then chain constructors, so that not every property needs to be set in the constructor. Something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }


    public Person(string name, double height, DateTime dob) : this(name, height)
    {
        this.DoB = dob;
    }

    public Person(string name, double height)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Height = height;
        this.DoB = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }
}
```

This means you can construct a new Person object using either two or three parameters, but all will be set (but if you use two then DOB will get a default of today):

```
Person person1 = new Person("Geoff", 1.8, new DateTime(1950, 5, 12));
Person person2 = new Person("John", 1.54); // Gets default DOB
```