# How to force a client to set certain properties

Tags: c#

My class has ten properties that must be set before the class can be used.

I want to force (or at least very strongly encourage, preferably with warnings) a user of my class to set these properties before calling any methods of the class.

I could use a constructor that takes values for all the properties as parameters but I don't want to because that many parameters would be unwieldy.

I could check the values of the properties inside all the methods of the class but this is too late - I want a compile-time check.

What can I do?

Comment: This is precisely what constructors are for.  They get the object into a state where it's usable - you can't guarantee that a client will or won't call methods or set properties etc.  If there are that many properties to set, perhaps the class is attempting to do too much and itself should be split into several smaller classes

Comment: you can move your properties into their own class, `PropClass`.  Then have your class have a property `PropClass` and take a `PropClass` parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Any other suggestion than using a constructor will wield the ugliest solutions. Can you show us a diagram of your class. Too many parameters hints at your class doing far too much.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Please can you elaborate?

Comment: @cja It's hard to say anything more without seeing the specifics of what you're doing.  But a client should have an understanding that after calling your constructor and passing in everything required, that it can immediately use the object.  The Builder Pattern mentioned in the answer below is probably the best bet if you can't refactor into multiple classes, and still don't want to pass all the parameters within the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can use some variation of the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) with fluent interface. You could have kind of steps or something where you can't skip some of the properties. For example to set property Y of the builder you will need the object returned by the method that sets property X.

```
new Builder().SetX(10).SetY(20) //compiles because SetX returns a class with SetY method
new Builder().SetY(20) //does not compile because the builder only has SetX method
```

To avoid having multiple classes you may have one class with multiple interfaces each of which exposes only one method.

On the other hand I would probably go for the constructor even with a lot of parameters

Comment: Yes, Builder pattern is nice for this kind of problem.  E.g. you have a complex object with internal constructors.  Then you design other objects for building out your object.  E.g. class called NetPipeFactory might contain the necessary methods for creating NetPipe objects (with complex configurations).  Or maybe you have a class called Graphics that creates itself with methods like FromImage, FromHnd, etc etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

---

Optional parameters should reduce mess of constructor parameters

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Property1 {get; private set;}
    public int Property2 {get; private set;}
    public int Property3 {get; private set;}

    public SomeClass(int some1 = 1, int some2 = 2, int some3 = 3)
    {
        SomeProperty1 = some1;
        SomeProperty2 = some2;
        SomeProperty3 = some3;
    }
}
```

Easy to use:

```
var a = new SomeClass(some3: 123);
```

---

You can try use nullables to `throw` if some value is not set

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int? _property1;
    public int Property1 { get { return (int)_property1.Value; } } // will throw

    public SomeClass() {}

    public int SomeMethod()
    {
       int val = _property1.Value; // will throw
       ...
       return 123;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with complex constructors, is they often don't explain the intended source.  For example say you have a class that can be created from a byte array, an image, a handle, a memory address, a base64 encoded string, or more, etc.

To just have constructors for each of them, you can't really portray that.  E.g. if one constructor takes a string (even if it's param name is base64String), it's not very intuitive.

A better approach I follow with complex constructors is to make my constructors private, and instead I expose the creation of my object through public static methods that return it's instanced self.

E.g., take the .Net Graphics class for example.  You can create the graphics class from an image or a windows handle etc, and for each it has methods "FromImage, FromHandle, etc".  Following that pattern, in my opinion, is more intuitive because you know you are creating it from an image just in the method name and this can be a decent way to tame complex constructors and initialization patterns.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stilgar noted the Builder pattern is a good answer.  Depending on the level of "encouragement" you want to give the end user, you could use a constructor with defaulted parameters.  This way they will see the things they should set (with Intellisense), but can also pick which ones they wish to set with named parameters.

```
        public ComplexObject(string P1 = "Test", int P2 = 123, double P3 = 3.1415927)
        {

        }
```

[image]